# Re splitting a merged development branch from Master in Git

Tags: git

I merged my development branch into my master branch and have made many changes since then. How could re-split the dev branch from the main branch and maintain the changes.

```
master -------merged -------changes -- mstr & dev ------need to split  ----master
dev------------^                                             \------------- dev
```

Comment: You started making your changes on the master branch? You should've just merged, tested, and switched back to the dev branch to continue development...

Comment: It sounds like you want to just: git checkout dev; git merge master;

Comment: No, I have only been working on the development branch. At one point I needed to commit an update to the master branch so I switched to "master" and merged the development branch, now I have a single branch. I need to split is back maintaining the updates.

Comment: @xdrone: "...now I have a single branch." Where has your original "dev" branch gone?

Comment: @xdrone please add more information about what you're trying to do and what you have already done, it's not clear. You'll get a better answer if you help us to understand your problem.

Comment: I recommend sitting down with paper (or whiteboard or whatever) and drawing a "commit graph".  Run `git log --graph --all` (maybe add `--oneline`) and/or use `gitk --all` or similar to get started.  Draw what you have now and then draw what you want to have.  This will probably answer your question, but if not, you now have two graphics to include with the question: "how do I turn (commit graph A) into (commit graph B)"

Answer (score 2):

If you continued development on your `dev` branch and on `master`, you simply need to rebase `dev` on top of `master`:

First, you merged `dev` to `master`:

```
x--x--x--x---X (master)
 \          /
  y--y--y--y (dev)
```

Then you make evolutions, on `dev` and `master`:

```
x--x--x--x---X--x--x (master)
 \          /
  y--y--y--y1--z--z (dev)
```

> How could re-split the dev branch from the main branch and maintain the changes.

```
git checkout dev
git rebase --onto master y1 dev
```

You could try a `git rebase -p`, for preserving merge commit, but in your case, simply rebasing the part which interests you, the '`z`' commits, is simpler.

```
x--x--x--x---X--x--x (master)
 \          /       \
  y--y--y--y         z'--z' (dev rebased)
```

Comment: Is y1 on dev the historical commit ID I must refer to where the dev and the master branch were merged?

Comment: @xdrone `y1` is not the "merge commit" resulting from the merge of `dev` to `master`: that would be '`X`'. `y1` is the last commit on `dev`, when you merged `dev` to `master`. You need to remember that one (`y1`), because a `merge --onto master y1 dev` means: take all the commits *after* `y1` (meaning the '`z`' commits), up to `dev HEAD`, and moves them onto `master`, as the new `dev` branch.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you want to (figuratively) move your 'master' branch back to the point just before you did the the merge, and you want your current development work to be on your 'development' branch.

If I understand your desire correctly, that is essentially a swap of the two branch pointers, with a tweak to ensure you aren't pointing at the merge commit itself.

On master, use `git branch --move master new_develop` to rename master to the new name.

Then assuming your old development branch is pointing at that old merge commit (check this `gitk development`), use `git branch master development^2` to recreate master but at the 2nd parent of the development merge (note the swapped argument order).

Finally, `git branch --move new_develop development` to bring back your old branch name. Check it all with `gitk` or your favourite tool.